# BUILD FAILURE while installing DL4J

Tags: maven, dl4j

I'm trying tu buld projetct with DL4J .

I did the following steps from ths website : [https://deeplearning4j.konduit.ai/getting-started/quickstart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Av8iW.png)

When I do this command `mvn clean install`

I get the following error :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you modified something? Sorry if I'm not quite following what you did, but that error message indicates a missing pom.xml.
The specific steps you follow are:

1. Clone the repository

```sh
  git clone https://github.com/eclipse/deeplearning4j-examples
```

2. cd in to the directory

```sh
      cd deeplearning4j-examples/dl4j-examples
```

3. Run mvn clean install -DskipTests

```sh
   mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

What I think could have happened here is you were in the root of the project. The deeplearning4j examples actually do not have a root pom.xml. We used to, but that took too long for people just getting started.

Of note here as well is another submodule in the project:
https://github.com/eclipse/deeplearning4j-examples/tree/master/mvn-project-template

This contains the default getting started project.

The dl4j-examples contain samples for different use cases. Please pay attention to that when looking at both.

Hopefully this helps!